# How to add this to a JList

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlist

I want to add each item of List[i] into a different Jlist , for example the first jList would have Hello,bye,good,bad,nice,Ses,Iteme

I want to make 4 different JList,

- 1st one with Hello,bye,good,bad......
- 2nd one with 569.99,551.59,678.99,....
- 3rd one 55,52,72,.... and
- the last one with jlas,byew,good2

```
class List
{

    Info[] List;

    public void createList()
    {

        List = new Info[7];

        List[0] = new Info("Hello",569.99,55,"jlas");

        List[1] = new Info("bye",551.59,52,"byew");
        List[2] = new Info("good",678.99,72,"good2");
        List[3] = new Info("bad",4547.959,151,"bad2");
        List[4] = new Info("nice",3554.99,235,"wii-U.jpg");
        List[5] = new CInfo("Ses",1140.99,4,"das");
        List[6] = new Info("Iteme",584.95,5,"sade");    


    }
}
```

Comment: I want to make 4 different JList, the 1st one with Hello,bye,good,bad...... the 2ndone with 569.99,551.59,678.99,....  the 3rd one 55,52,72,.... and the last one with jlas,byew,good2,.....

Comment: You can always edit your own questions to add additional information; @Frakcool did this for you.

Comment: You have a class and a variable with the same name? `List` class and `List` an array of Info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take all the values add them to a `ListModel`

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
for (Info info : List) {
    model.addElement(model);
}
```

Then add this model to each of your `JList`s...

```
JList list1 = new JList(model);
JList list2 = new JList(model);
JList list3 = new JList(model);
JList list4 = new JList(model);
```

Now, here comes the funky part, create a `ListCellRenderer` for each different way you want to display the data...

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JList;

public class ListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public class InfoNameListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            if (value instanceof Info) {
                Info info = (Info)value;
                value = info.getName(); // Or what ever getter you have available for such things
            }
            return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus); 
        }



    }

}
```

And apply it to the appropriate list...

```
list1.setCellRenderer(new InfoNameListCellRenderer());
```

Remember, it's the models responsibility to model the data, it's the renderer's responsibility to renderer it.  Don't change the model to meet your rendering requirements.

Take a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more details